# Qual a diferença entre Start e Publish em um servidor no Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Quando eu adiciono o Tomcat como um servidor no Eclipse, aparece `Start` e `Publish`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 3):

[Start](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwsrtins.html&cp=66_4_0_7_2): inicia o serviço do tomcat pelo eclipse.

[Publish](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twpub.html): Coloca as modificações de código ou jsp em vigor sem precisar reiniciar o servidor.

> Publishing envolve copiar arquivos (projetos, recursos e
>   configurações do servidor) para o local correto para o servidor de
>   encontrar e usá-los.

Comment: Publish é o Hot Deploy ?